Proving the Absence of a Property without Contrapositive
I am currently learning indirect forms of proof, including the contrapositive proof. Consider the following proposition:
Suppose $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $3 \nmid n^2$, then $3 \nmid n$.
While this is routine to prove using the contrapositive, I wanted to consider proving this statement directly. But this left me in uncharted territory. To this point, I have only ever proved that a particular integer, set, or mathematical element possesses a particular feature, not that it does not possess a particular feature.
While my experience is limited, it seems that proving that a mathematical element possesses a particular feature is much easier than proving that it does not. For instance, if I were to prove that $3 \mid n$, I would just need to find a way to show that $n = 3k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. However, to prove that $3 \nmid n$, I would need to show that $n \neq 3k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. In short, $3 \mid n$ forces me to find one integer that satisfies the condition, whereas $3 \nmid n$ forces me to show that infinite integers do not.
I write all of this to say: how should I think about proving the absence of a given property? After stumbling around, I came up with my best guess in the context of the original proposition:
Suppose $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $3 \nmid n^2$. Suppose also that $3 \mid n$. Since $3 \nmid n^2$, the unique prime factorization of $n^2$ does not contain 3. Likewise, because $3 \mid n$ and $3$ is prime, the unique prime factorization of $n$ contains 3. But, since $n^2 = n \cdot n$, the unique prime factorization of $n^2$ is simply the prime factorization of $n$ repeated twice. Thus, if the prime factorization of $n$ contains $3$, then the prime factorization of $n^2$ must also contain $3$....contradiction!
From this exercise, I have found that proof by contradiction is an effective way to prove the absence of a given property. More generally, is this often the case? I am also aware that in certain contexts, proving that a mathematical element has a different but related property is equivalent to proving that it does not have the property of interest. For instance, proving that an integer is even is the same as proving that it is not odd. My question pertains to scenarios where such a relationship between properties does not exist or is not readily apparent.

Note that your proof by contradiction was really a proof by contrapositive. You say it as much in "Thus, if the prime factorization of $n$ contains $3$, then the prime factorization of $n^2$ must also contain $3$...."

To a mathematician, the tools of logic are just that: tools. Proof by contradiction is a useful tool. Proof by contrapositive is another useful tool. If a tool works, use it!

Nonetheless, perhaps you might be interested in alternative logics, such as intuitionistic logic.

"How should I think about proving the absence of a given property?" The short answer is "just like proving the presence of a given property." For one, absence of a given property often is presence of a the negation of said property (whether you're tying to show a set is infinite or that it is not finite, or that a number is composite or not prime depends on what exactly you're trying to do). ...and how do you figure that out? Experience and sometimes guessing.

To prove something most of us proceed roughly as follows: You read the problem, think about what it says, whether it's plausible, and what you already know about it, then you look at the tools and proof techniques at your disposal, pick the one that seems most likely to you to work and start working. Maybe you get stuck, and after trying for a while you decide that maybe the technique you chose was not ideal, so you backtrack and try something else. Rinse and repeat until the problem is solved or you've run out of steam.

Note that in logic $\neg P$ is usually defined as $P\to\bot$ (, where $\bot$ is a false statement). Therefore, the most direct approach to a proof for $\neg P$ should be assuming $P$ and deriving a falsehood.

...point being that learning basic proof techniques is all well and good, but how and when to apply them is something that can only really be learned through experience. I'd focus less on patterns of applicability and more on (a) understanding the techniques themselves and then (b) practicing proofs. It's more of an art than a science.

@Randall are all proofs by contradictions proofs by contrapositives?

This is a great question, and your analysis of the situation is very cogent, especially this bit:

In short, $3 \mid n$ forces me to find one integer that satisfies the condition, whereas $3 \nmid n$ forces me to show that infinite integers do not.

Basically here is how I think about this for myself: if I am trying to prove a statement of the form $p \Rightarrow q$, then I ask whether it would be easier to prove the contrapositive $\neg q \Rightarrow \neg p$ instead. The way I decide between these is to ask which of the hypotheses $p$ or $\neg q$ is more productive, in the sense of easier to prove things from.
In this situation, $3 \mid n$ is a very productive hypothesis: it lets me produce an integer $m$ such that $n = 3m$, and I can do things with this, namely square it to get $n^2 = 9m^2$. By contrast, it's more difficult to argue starting with the hypothesis $3 \nmid n^2$, since as you say this is a claim that infinitely many equalities do not hold (namely that $n^2 \neq 3m$ for any $m$), and we have more good and intuitive ways to turn equalities into equalities than we have ways to turn non-equalities into non-equalities.
Here is an example of a use of proof by contrapositive to prove the pigeonhole principle:

We might as well prove the general form: if at least $mn + 1$ pigeons are sorted into $n$ holes then at least one hole contains at least $m + 1$ pigeons.


The contrapositive is: if all $n$ holes contain at most $m$ pigeons then there are at most $mn$ pigeons. But this is clear, we just add up the numbers of pigeons in the holes. (Note that we need to say "at least $mn + 1$ pigeons" and not "$mn + 1$ pigeons" to get this to work.)

Formally, the claim is that if $x_1, \dots x_n$ are non-negative integers such that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ge mn + 1$ then $\text{max}_i(x_i) \ge m + 1$. To me the contrapositive stands out here as involving a more productive hypothesis, because the negation of $\text{max}_i(x_i) \ge m + 1$ is $\text{max}_i(x_i) \le m$, or equivalently that $x_i \le m$ for all $i$, which gives me a strong condition on all of the $x_i$ that immediately implies the desired result, since just summing these inequalities gives $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \le mn$.
The difficulty with proving this statement directly is that the hypothesis $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ge mn + 1$ doesn't tell you as much about each $x_i$ individually; at least in terms of formal algebraic manipulations we can't get from here to a statement about any individual $x_i$ (and in fact any individual $x_i$ could take on any value between $0$ and $mn + 1$). Somehow in order to argue in this direction we have to break the symmetry between the $x_i$ (for example by considering the largest one). In the contrapositive direction it's not necessary to break any symmetries!
This can also be phrased as a proof by contradiction but my personal preference is that proofs by contrapositive should be clearly phrased that way, because then all the statements you prove along the way are true. It obscures what's going on to phrase things as proofs by contradiction unnecessarily, and in my opinion it makes it easier to make mistakes too. I discuss this a bit in the linked answer. For example your proof by contradiction has the same content as the proof by contrapositive; you can just use the assumption $3 \mid n$ and not use the assumption $3 \nmid n^2$, which is not necessary.
The situation where I use proof by contradiction is where it really seems like I need to assume both $p$ and $\neg q$ to start proving anything. Unfortunately I can't think of a really good example off the top of my head.
